# Keep getting 'undefined' when reading a string in Cloud Firestore

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm using the code from https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

sometimes it works, sometimes it comes back 'undefined' I guess I need to make it await the response somehow but I'm not sure what to do.  Is there any way to ensure that the get command completes before moving onto the next step in the code?

```
  var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
  var getDoc = cityRef.get()
   .then(doc => {
   if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
     console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
    }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting document', err);
    });
```

Comment: How is this related to actions-on-google? I feel like there's not enough context here to answer your question.

Comment: This is javascript from an actions on google project, it would read data from the database and use that in the <speak> commands...

Comment: The snippet itself is fine, but I think your issue is not properly setting up the asynchronous flow. Using method.then(...).catch(...) is fine, as long as you make sure to return promises as needed.